# Azure says it can't replicate Linux VM because that version is unsupported

Tags: linux, redhat, azure

When I try to replicate any of our Linux servers running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 into Azure, replication fails with the following error message.

> Provider error message: Protection could not be enabled.
>
> Provider error possible causes: Push installation of the mobility
>   service to the source machine 192.168.21.161,192.168.0.161 failed with
>   error code EP0881. The Linux version of the source machine is
>   currently unsupported.
>
> Provider error recommended action: The operating system running on
>   virtual machine 192.168.21.161,192.168.0.161 is currently unsupported.
>   For more details on operating systems supported by Azure Site Recovery
>   and other pre-requisites go to https://aka.ms/asr-os-support.

However won that link it says that the following machines are supported.

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux: 5.2 to 5.11, 6.1 to 6.9, 7.0 to 7.4

Why is it failing saying that it's unsupported?

Comment: Have you asked Azure support? This is platform-specific.

Comment: RHEL 5 has reached end of life. And the problem is probably something out of date on the system anyway. Or Azure dropped support for RHEL 5 and didn't update the doc. My first step would be to bring the system up to date.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used Azure myself to test it, the system version you are trying to build has reached it's EOL and won't be receiving any updates even with a regular RHEL license. The earliest version compatible with Azure environment appears to be RHEL 6, so it is possible that it has never been compatible with the service. I guess you have two options:

- Negotiate an hipotetical and potentially expensive support agreement with Red Hat so they assist you on tweaking whatever is needed to get the Azure agent to work with an End Of Life product. But you'll end up with a very expensive outdated OS.
- Bite the bullet and migrate to version 6 or 7 and use an OS that is within its life cycle. Maybe you are even lucky enough to qualify for their [program to migrate licenses to Cloud services](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/cloud-access#program-details)